# How to bundle up a library's css into bundle.js using Webpack 2?

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-2, material-components

I'm trying to do a very basic setup for my frontend frameworks using Webpack 2. I want to bundle up [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) and it's css but I can't figure out how to bundle the CSS too.

I expect to have a `bundle.js` that I can load on an HTML file and be able to call `mdc` components. Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/communications/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And here's my entry file `index.js`

```
import * as mdc from 'material-components-web';
```

The problem is that I am a little bit lost on how should I bundle the CSS. The syntax is probably something similar to `@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";` But I'm not sure where should I put it, is it on the `index.js` file, or should I create a `styles.scss` file and import that one on `index.js` etc. I'm overall lost.

The reason for this setup is because our codebase use components from [material-design-lite](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite), `jQuery` and `Bootstrap` but it doesn't have a build task yet, so this is kind of like the first step.

Comment: does importing `mdc` throw any errors or is this a general question?

Comment: Nop, but since in the "getting started" section they include both js and css (through a CDN) I figured i had to import both js and css too through webpack

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need  style-loader(https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) which will include your css in bundle.js

```js
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: How should I import the `material-components-web` sass file? can you provide an example?